# Probability of 2 Women followed by 2 Men

Tags: probability

The music school has 3 women and 4 men audition for solo performances. In deciding on an evening program the director must choose 4 different soloists performing *in a particular order*. If a program is selected at random, determine the probability that the program consists of two women followed by two men.

I've been stuck on this question. I'm not sure how to implement that girls are chosen before the guys. I've gotten 18/35 for choosing 2 guys and 2 girls, but i'm not sure what to do afterwards.

18/35 was gotten by doing:

(3C2) * (4C2) / (7C4)

Answer (score 3):

The first must be a girl with probability $\frac{3}{7}$

The second must be a girl with probability $\frac{2}{6}$

The third must be a boy with probability $\frac{4}{5}$

The fourth must be a boy with probability $\frac{3}{4}$

All together,

$$\frac{3}{7}\cdot \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4}\approx0.0857$$

Comment: Oh so you don't need to use any equations? or can you do this with an equation?

Comment: You can do it either way. In this case, it is more simple to do it without.

Comment: Oh my I feel so dumb now hahahaha...totally forgot simples fractions work just fine

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat It's still good to know how to do it your way though.

Comment: @Remy it's easier to check answer in exam setting using my way but getting finally answer using yours is a lot faster without a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track for choosing but you forgot to impose the order.

We should instead have
$$\frac{\binom32 2! \binom42 2!}{\binom74 4!}$$
to account for all the orders.

The reason for the two $2!$'s is that the girls' queue and the guys' queue must be arranged separately so that the girls start first. In the denominator, there's no restricted on the order so we just use $4!$.